# How to disable/enable input fields of a form dynamically on Django

Tags: django, forms

Is it possible to dynamically enable/disable fields, based on something entered on the form? i.e. the user press one choice on a radio button and a given text field is enabled.

Comment: you can do that using javascript/jquery...

Comment: Building on what @HadeS said, you would also need to make sure that any fields you enable/disable also allow blank on your model if you're using a ModelForm.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I've never used javascripy/jquery, are there any recommended references or keywords for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    radio = $('#yourRadioField'); 
    dynamicField = $('#yourDynamicField'); 

    dynamicField.hide(); 
    if ( radio.is(':checked') ) { dynamicField.show() } 

});
```

Those are the bare bones of showing and hiding form fields with jquery. For future reference, the questions on stackoverflow tend to be narrowly defined. Broad questions should be first winnowed down with a few google searches.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.I have indeed done some google/stackoverflow searches, but I couldn't find anything useful. In fact, I haven't even found anything that have specifically pointed me into using jquery/javascript. Maybe because I'm new on web development, so i don't have many keywords in mind for searching.